# Windows could not start the SQL Server Agent (mssqlserver) service on Local Computer

Tags: sql-server

Windows could not start the SQL Server Agent (`mssqlserver`) service on Local Computer;

> Error 1075: The dependency service does not exist or has been marked for deletion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely the `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` service is not started or doesn't exist. The SQL Server Agent is dependent on that service and it can't be found. That's the error message.

Check out if you have the MSSQLSERVER service installed and running and try again. MSSQLSERVER means that it is the default instance of an MS SQL Server install.

Answer (score 0):

Try To stop other SQL servers running on the machine and try to start the one that facing this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).